# Create custom query in Strapi with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, strapi

I'm new to both Strapi and Mongoose, so I apologise if this is a stupid question.

Following the docs (https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html) I'm trying to create a custom query in Strapi in which I want to return the whole collection called `people` sorted by name desc. But when I hit the endpoint I get a 500 error and checking the terminal the error message is `CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "alldesc" at path "_id" for model "people"`.

Here's my code:

`services/people.js`

```
module.exports = {
  findByNameDesc() {
    const result = strapi
      .query("people")
      .model.find()
      .sort({ name: "descending" });

    return result.map((entry) => entry.toObject());
  },
};
```

`controllers/people.js`

```
module.exports = {
  async alldesc(ctx) {
    const entities = await strapi.services.people.findByNameDesc(ctx);

    return entities.map((entity) =>
      sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.people })
    );
  },
};
```

`config/routes.json`

```
{
  "routes": [

     ...

    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/people/alldesc",
      "handler": "people.alldesc",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: even when removing `.sort({ name: "descending" });` from the query, the error is still there, so I'm thinking that maybe there's something wrong in the way I use the service in the controller?

Comment: Does the error still happen if you do not execute `toObject`?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Yes it still does. Seems to me that there's something wrong in the way I use the service in the controller or in the query, but I cannot figure out what it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `routes.json`. Basically seems like Strapi doesn't like the slash `/` so instead of `/people/alldesc` I tried `/people-alldesc` and it worked.

Also in the service there's no need for `return result.map((entry) => entry.toObject());`, that causes anther error, simply doing `return result` works.